# Finding Max/Min integers from user generated text file c++

Tags: inputstream

I am using VS 2017. I am attempting to open a text file that the user inputs and read the integers from that text file and then output the largest and smallest numbers from that text file.

Issues:
I cannot seem to figure out how to open a user generated text file.
it skips the loop entirely and does not read any numbers from the text file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Right now my output is Max: 0 Min: 0

This is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    ifstream fin;
    double min = 0;
    double max = 0;
    int next;
    double sum = 0;
    string fileName;


    cout << "Enter the name of the file you would like to use: " << endl;
    cin >> fileName;

    fin.open(fileName.c_str());

    if (fin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file opening failed." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }


    while (fin >> next)
    {
        if (next > max)
        {
            max = next;
        }
        if (next < min)
        {
            min = next;
        }
    }

    cout << "Min: " << min << " Max: " << max;

    return 0;
}
```